# Whats wrong with my rig

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on

Im using Blenrig addon. I have align the bones in edit mode and wiht ctrl+P automatic weight parent.

Download the [Addon](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/56965fc3c379cf44546120e1) for Free

[image]

**Edit Mode**

[image]

**Pose Mode**

[image]

Any suggestion or help how to fix it and rig a smooth working hand.

Comment: Please continue to use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files.

Comment: @RayMairlot i was getting error that time. Update know plz check it.